# 'PyCapture2.Image' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, tkinter, camera

i'm trying to show a picture in TKInter. I'm using the Pycapture library in a FLEA3 Point Grey Camera. I can take the picture, but when i try to show in my GUI, show the error saying Pycapture does not have the attribute "read"

import PyCapture2
from sys import exit
from PIL import ImageTk
import PIL.Image
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

enableEmbeddedTimestamp(camera, True)

```
camera.startCapture()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(grabImages(camera, 1)))
showImage = Label(imageContainer, image=img)
showImage.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand="yes")
imageLabel.create_image(20, 20, anchor="n", image=img)

camera.stopCapture()
```